# Harmonic Sum and cardinality of continuum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} 
\end{equation}
diverges.

In most of the books, it is proved as follows:\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} &=& 1 + \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+....\\
&\geq &1 + \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+....
\end{eqnarray}
In otherwords, for each $N$, there exists a $k$ such that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n} \geq \sum_{k=1}^{2^k} \frac{1}{n} \geq 1+\frac{k}{2}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n} \geq \sum_{k=1}^{2^{2k}} \frac{1}{n} \geq 1+k
\end{equation}
If $k \rightarrow \infty$, then $N \rightarrow \infty$ and vice versa.
The growth of the right hand side of last equation is in logarithmic fashion.

Let us consider the number of terms required to get the sum output as $k+1$.
For each $k$ in the right side, it requires at most $\mathfrak{N}=2^{2k}$ terms from the middle sum.
To move from $k$ to $k+1$ on the right hand side, it requires, $2^{2k+2}-2^{2k}$ terms, that is 
a large number.

I am not sure, whether the following statement is true.

Statment1:
Let $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4,...,n\}$ and $\mathcal{P}(X)$ = power set of $X$.
Obviously, $|X| = n$ and $|\mathcal{P}(X)| = 2^n$. If $n \rightarrow \infty$, then $X \rightarrow(???) \mathbb{N}$. So, $|X| \rightarrow \aleph_{0}$ and |$\mathcal{P}(X)| \rightarrow 2^{\aleph_{0}} = \mathfrak{c}$.

If statement1 is true, from equation (5), as $k \rightarrow \infty $, $\mathfrak{N} \rightarrow \mathfrak{c}$. Although, $\sum_{k=1}^{2^{2k}} \frac{1}{n}$ seems to have uncountably infinite terms, when $k \rightarrow \infty$, the dominating harmonic series has countably infinite terms. I know something is wrong here. But, I am not able to grasp it. 
My idea is not to prove the harmonic is divergent or convergent. I know it is divergent using other contrary proof. But, what is wrong here? 
Is statement 1 false?

Comment: How do you define convergence of sets ($X\rightarrow\Bbb N$) and cardinals ($\mathcal P(X)\rightarrow 2^{\aleph_0}$)?

Comment: I don't say they converge. But, if I don't know the symbol to represent that. Like X grows and grows and become $\mathbb{N}$ and sorry, it should be cardinality of the set and I have corrected the post

Comment: In any case, the $\mathcal P(X)$ doesn't "converge", in any meaningful way of formalizing this, to $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$, despite $X$ "converging" to $\Bbb N$. To be more precise, the union of $\mathcal P(X)$ for all $X$ as in your question isn't $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$, but rather it contains only the finite subsets of $\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that for any positive integer $n$ the $2^{n}$:th partial sum of the harmonic series grows linearly in $n$; for clarity the sum begins with the number $1/2$ rather than with $1\ .$
$$\frac{n}{2} < \sum_{k=2}^{2^{n}}\frac{1}{k} < n \ .$$ This is equivalent to the $n$:th partial sum of the harmonic series growing logarithmically fast (to base 2) in $n$. $$\frac{\log_{2}n}{2} < \sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k} < \log_{2}n\ .$$ If you want the $n$:th partial sum to equal some positive number $(M)$ then you need the partial sum to contain more than $\sqrt{2^{M}}$ number of terms but fewer than $2^{M}$ number of terms.